# Delete all empty folders in Java

Tags: java, file, recursion, directory

I'd like to write a function that deletes all empty folders, with the option to ignore certain file types (allowed file types are stored in the hashmap) and tell if it should look inside directories.

**Calling:**

```
HashMap<String, Boolean> allowedFileTypes = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
allowedFileTypes.put("pdf", true);
deleteEmptyFolders("ABSOLUTE PATH", allowedFileTypes, true);
```

**Function:**

```
public static void deleteEmptyFolders(String folderPath, HashMap<String, Boolean> allowedFileTypes, boolean followDirectory) {

    File targetFolder = new File(folderPath);
    File[] allFiles = targetFolder.listFiles();


    if (allFiles.length == 0)
        targetFolder.delete();

    else {
        boolean importantFiles = false;

        for (File file : allFiles) {

            String fileType = "folder";
            if (!file.isDirectory())
                fileType = file.getName().substring(file.getName().lastIndexOf('.') + 1);

            if (!importantFiles)
                importantFiles = (allowedFileTypes.get(fileType) != null);

            if (file.isDirectory() && followDirectory)
                deleteEmptyFolders(file.getAbsolutePath(), allowedFileTypes, followDirectory);
        }

        // if there are no important files in the target folder
        if (!importantFiles)
            targetFolder.delete();
    }
}
```

The problem is that nothing is happening, even though it looks through all folders till the end. Is this a good approach or am I missing something completely?

Comment: Any reason you're using a HashMap instead of a HashSet?

Comment: @aioobe Now that you mention it. No.. I will make it a set, because I will only check if it nulls. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this can help you a bit: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20281958/2496309

Comment: @Mikrobus You are right that was it. You have to delete all files before you can delete a folder. Also sometimes there are hidden config files in the folders, that can be tricky. Thanks you could post it as an answer.

Comment: @aioobe Thanks for your support. I already solved the problem.

Answer (score 7):

This piece of code recursively delete all the empty folders or directory:

```
public class DeleteEmptyDir {
private static final String FOLDER_LOCATION = "E:\\TEST";
private static boolean isFinished = false;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    do {
        isFinished = true;
        replaceText(FOLDER_LOCATION);
    } while (!isFinished);
}

private static void replaceText(String fileLocation) {
    File folder = new File(fileLocation);
    File[] listofFiles = folder.listFiles();
    if (listofFiles.length == 0) {
        System.out.println("Folder Name :: " + folder.getAbsolutePath() + " is deleted.");
        folder.delete();
        isFinished = false;
    } else {
        for (int j = 0; j < listofFiles.length; j++) {
            File file = listofFiles[j];
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                replaceText(file.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This program never ends if there does not exists a folder that is empty.

Comment: replaceText??? what

Answer (score 2):

Shortest code I could come up with is following Java >=8 code:

```
        Files.walk(Paths.get("/my/base/dir/"))
                .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
                .map(Path::toFile)
                .filter(File::isDirectory)
                .forEach(File::delete);
```

Add a second (or more) filter statement with whatever clause you need to include/exclude certain folders. **File::delete** should not delete folders with contents.
Use at own risk.

Comment: This does not delete empty folders recursively.

Answer (score 1):

You can use code to delete empty folders using Java.

```
public static long deleteFolder(String dir) {

        File f = new File(dir);
        String listFiles[] = f.list();
        long totalSize = 0;
        for (String file : listFiles) {

            File folder = new File(dir + "/" + file);
            if (folder.isDirectory()) {
                totalSize += deleteFolder(folder.getAbsolutePath());
            } else {
                totalSize += folder.length();
            }
        }

        if (totalSize ==0) {
            f.delete();
        }

        return totalSize;
    }
```

Comment: file is undifined

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin:

```
fun deleteAllEmptyDirectories(rootPath: Path): Collection<Path> =
    mutableListOf<Path>()
        .apply {
            Files.walk(testPath)
                .sorted { p1, p2 -> p2.count() - p1.count() }
                .map { it.toFile() }
                .filter { it.isDirectory }
                .forEach {
                    if (it.listFiles().all { el -> el.isDirectory && contains(el.toPath()) }) {
                        val path = it.toPath()
                        add(path)
                        Files.delete(path)
                    }
                }
        }
```

Test:

```
 private val testPath = Path.of("build", javaClass.simpleName, UUID.randomUUID().toString())

@Test
fun test() {
    Files.createDirectory(testPath)

    val dirWithTwoEmptySubdirs = Files.createDirectory(testPath.resolve("dirWithTwoEmptySubdirs"))
    val dir1 = Files.createDirectory(dirWithTwoEmptySubdirs.resolve("dir1"))
    val dir2 = Files.createDirectory(dirWithTwoEmptySubdirs.resolve("dir2"))
    val dirWithOneDiffDir = Files.createDirectory(testPath.resolve("dirWithOneDiffDir"))
    var emptyDir = Files.createDirectory(dirWithOneDiffDir.resolve("empty"))
    val notEmptyDir = Files.createDirectory(dirWithOneDiffDir.resolve("notempty"))
    Files.writeString(notEmptyDir.resolve("file.txt"), "asdf")

    assertEquals(
        setOf<Path>(dirWithTwoEmptySubdirs, dir1, dir2, emptyDir),
        deleteAllEmptyDirectories(testPath).toSet()
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading all answers and concluding that all of them have at least one problem I still had to write it myself:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Temp {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String path = "D:\\";
    deleteEmpty(new File(path));
  }

  private static int deleteEmpty(File file) {
    List<File> toBeDeleted = Arrays.stream(file.listFiles()).sorted() //
        .filter(File::isDirectory) //
        // Recursive call to delete sub-directories. 
        // If all files in the sub-directory where deleted, also delete this directory. 
        .filter(f -> f.listFiles().length == deleteEmpty(f)) //
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    int size = toBeDeleted.size();
    toBeDeleted.forEach(t -> {
      final String path = t.getAbsolutePath();
      final boolean delete = t.delete();
      System.out.println("Deleting: \t" + delete + "\t" + path);
    });
    return size;
  }

}
```

Comment: OP does recursive file deletion, so you'll have to call `deleteEmpty` for each file you find. Also, don't hesitate to comment on any problems you see in other's answers. It increases the general quality of answers! ;)

Comment: This does delete all subfolders, I added some comments to explain the code a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

```
Files.walk(Paths.get("C:\\Temp\\samplefolder")) // works recursively
.map(Path::toFile) // use Java File object
.filter(File::isDirectory) // only consider directories
.filter(f -> f.length() == 0) // make sure no files or directories are in it
.filter(f -> FileUtils.sizeOfDirectory(f) == 0) // use Apache FileUtils here
.forEach(File::delete); // go and delete
```

This code should work also without Apache Fileutils.sizeOfDirectory() as it counts files and sub-directories inside a directory already.