# Selenium WebDriver - Delete cookies and restart the browser during the test

Tags: java, selenium, cookies, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have a test case to test is the cart items still exist after delete cookies and restart the browser

1. Add the items to shopping cart (there will be a count to indicated number of items added)
2. `Delete the cookies` on the browser,
3. `Close the browser`
4. `Relaunch the browser`
5. Check is the shopping cart count items still exists

my main code are below.

```
// 1. Add items to shopping cart
// code go here

// 2. Clear the cookies on the browser
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();         
driver.navigate().refresh();
// 3. Close the browser
driver.close();                             

ProfilesIni firProfiles = new ProfilesIni();        
FirefoxProfile wbdrverprofile = firProfiles.getProfile("default");  
// 4. Relaunch the browser      
driver = new FirefoxDriver(wbdrverprofile);                 
driver.get("http://www.google.com");        

Boolean isCartCountExists = driver.findElements(By.id(cartCount)).size()!=0;
if(isCartCountExists == true){
    System.out.println("Test Failed.");
}else{
    System.out.println("Test Passed.")
}
```

`@AfterTest` code

```
@AfterTest
    public void closeBrowser(){

        driver.close();
        ExistingmozillaBrowser=null;

    }
```

Getting error log below

```
[TestNG] Running:

FAILED CONFIGURATION: @AfterTest closeBrowser
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf', time: '2014-10-23 20:03:00'
System info: host: 'C111400215M4232', ip: '192.168.0.11', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_45'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:593)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:614)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.close(RemoteWebDriver.java:463)
    at testCases.SuiteBase.closeWebBrowser(SuiteBase.java:380)
    at testCases.ModuleOne.myTestCase01.closeBrowser(myTestCase01.java:387)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:564)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.afterRun(TestRunner.java:1014)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:621)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 127.0.0.1:7056 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:140)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:318)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:363)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:219)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:86)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.fallBackExecute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:215)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:184)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.execute(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:165)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver$LazyCommandExecutor.execute(FirefoxDriver.java:362)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:572)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:72)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:123)
    ... 40 more

FAILED: myTestCase01Test("myTestCase01", "pc", "laptop", "2", "usd")
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf', time: '2014-10-23 20:03:00'
System info: host: 'C111400215M4232', ip: '192.168.0.11', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_45'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:593)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElements(RemoteWebDriver.java:377)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementsByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:453)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElements(By.java:352)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElements(RemoteWebDriver.java:340)
    at pageObjects.HomePage.check_noCartCount(HomePage.java:550)
    at testCases.ModuleOne.myTestCase01.myTestCase01Test(myTestCase01.java:317)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 127.0.0.1:7056 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:140)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:318)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:363)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:219)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:86)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.fallBackExecute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:215)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:184)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.execute(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:165)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver$LazyCommandExecutor.execute(FirefoxDriver.java:362)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:572)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:72)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:123)
    ... 44 more


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
    Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

It seem like after close the browser, the test unable to continue after restart. Any help will be appreciate. Thanks.

Comment: Please post all your test code. Without it is hard to help you.

Comment: After `driver.close()`, you will have to re-initialize `driver`. Although one way to use cookies is to use the `user-dir` argument.

Answer (score 4):

I think this way should work:

Steps (this is a chrome example):

- Use the `user-dir` argument in your browser configuration:

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "res/chromedriver.exe");
  DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
  options.addArguments("test-type");
  options.addArguments("start-maximized");
  options.addArguments("user-data-dir=D:/temp/");
  capabilities.setCapability("chrome.binary","res/chromedriver.exe");
  capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY,options);
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
  ```
- Add the items to your shopping cart
- Close the driver (do NOT quit)

  ```
  driver.close();
  ```
- In the background, [**delete**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20281835/how-to-delete-a-folder-with-files-using-java) the `user-dir` which is `D:/temp/` which has the browser profile. This would be the cookie deleting part.
- Re-initialise the driver and verify shopping cart is empty

  ```
  driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
  ```

PS: I hope this helps. I have seen that this type of code can be used to test the "Remember me" functionality. I am not so sure about shopping cart.

Answer (score 0):

**Java:**

```
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;


private static WebDriver driver;

public static void restartDriver() {
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();         // Clear Cookies on the browser
    driver.quit();
    driver = null;
    driver = new ChromeDriver();

}
```

This is the shortest way to start a session.