# Resource leak in Files.list(Path dir) when stream is not explicitly closed?

Tags: java, stream, java-8

I recently wrote a small app that periodically checked the content of a directory. After a while, the app crashed because of too many open file handles. After some debugging, I found the error in the following line:

```java
Files.list(Paths.get(destination)).forEach(path -> {
     // To stuff
});
```

I then checked the javadoc (I probably should have done that earlier) for `Files.list` and found:

```
* <p> The returned stream encapsulates a {@link DirectoryStream}.
* If timely disposal of file system resources is required, the
* {@code try}-with-resources construct should be used to ensure that the
* stream's {@link Stream#close close} method is invoked after the stream
* operations are completed
```

To me, "timely disposal" still sounds like the resources are going to be released eventually, before the app quits. I looked through the JDK (1.8.60) code but I wasn't able to find any hint about the file handles opened by `Files.list` being released again.

I then created a small app that explicitly calls the garbage collector after using `Files.list` like this:

```java
while (true) {
    Files.list(Paths.get("/")).forEach(path -> {
      System.out.println(path);
    });
    Thread.sleep(5000);

    System.gc();
    System.runFinalization();
}
```

When I checked the open file handles with `lsof -p <pid>` I could still see the list of open file handles for "/" getting longer and longer.

My question now is: Is there any hidden mechanism that should eventually close no longer used open file handles in this scenario? Or are these resources in fact never disposed and the javadoc is a bit euphemistic when talking about "timely disposal of file system resources"?

Comment: You're right, if you don't close the stream then the file handle won't ever be closed.

Comment: But, if your process exits, the OS will clean up after it.  I suspect by "timely" they meant "before the end of the process"

Comment: That might be. Although I find it not very intuitive that you are not supposed to use the stream like that. Also IDEs don't seem to warn you about this potential resource leak, even though it should be easy to find.

Comment: IDEs don't warn because almost all `Stream`s don't need to be closed.  Ideally `Files.list()` would have some annotation like `@CloseTheReturnedStream` that IDEs could understand.

Comment: Your test code assumes that automatic cleanup has to be performed via `finalize()`, but usually, modern code uses `PhantomReference` based cleaners, which are not triggered by `System.runFinalization()`. So even if there is an automatic cleanup, you won’t detect it with your code. But looking at [the implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/sun/nio/fs/UnixDirectoryStream.java) or [its creator](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/sun/nio/fs/UnixFileSystemProvider.java#402) you won’t see a cleaner…

Comment: After spending 2 days on hunting a related bug, I think the JavaDoc is poor here and needs a clear warning. It indicates, that the stream will be closed at some point, but in a server environment that's basically "never' until serverapp shutdown.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you close the Stream, `Files.list()` does close the underlying `DirectoryStream` it uses to stream the files, so there should be no resource leak as long as you close the Stream.

You can see where the `DirectoryStream` is closed in the source code for `Files.list()` here:

```
return StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(it, Spliterator.DISTINCT), false)
                    .onClose(asUncheckedRunnable(ds));
```

The key thing to understand is that a `Runnable` is registered with the Stream using `Stream::onClose` that is called when the stream itself is closed.  That Runnable is created by a factory method, `asUncheckedRunnable` that creates a `Runnable` that closes the resource passed into it, translating any `IOException` thrown during the `close()` to an `UncheckedIOException`

You can safely assure that the `DirectoryStream` is closed by ensuring the `Stream` is closed like this:

```
try (Stream<Path> files = Files.list(Paths.get(destination))){
    files.forEach(path -> {
         // Do stuff
    });
}
```

Comment: You saved my day!

Comment: where are we closing stream in this piece of code exactly?

Comment: @Simrankaur, this is an example of try_with_resources. The variables declared inside the parentheses after `try` will be automatically closed, regardless of whether the try block completes normally or exceptionally.

Comment: Great, Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the IDE part: Eclipse performs resource leak analysis based on local variables (and explicit resource allocation expressions), so you only have to extract the stream to a local variable:

```
Stream<Path> files =Files.list(Paths.get(destination));
files.forEach(path -> {
 // To stuff
});
```

Then Eclipse will tell you

> Resource leak: 'files' is never closed

Behind the scenes the analysis works with a cascade of exceptions:

1. All `Closeable`s need closing
2. `java.util.stream.Stream` (which is Closeable) does **not** need closing
3. All streams produced by methods in `java.nio.file.Files` **do** need closing

This strategy was developed in coordination with the library team when they discussed whether or not `Stream` should be `AutoCloseable`.

Answer (score 1):

```
   List<String> fileList = null;

   try (Stream<Path> list = Files.list(Paths.get(path.toString()))) {
   fileList = 
     list.filter(Files::isRegularFile).map(Path::toFile).map(File::getAbsolutePath)
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
   } catch (IOException e) {
    logger.error("Error occurred while reading email files: ", e);
  }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

I've incurred same issue during file processing, what worked out is try-with-resource, follow below snippet if someone is still struggling:

```
        try(Stream<Path> files = Files.list(Paths.get("/some/location/"))){
        List<File> allFiles = files.map(Path::toFile).filter(File :: isFile).collect(Collectors.toList());
        for (File file : allFiles) {
            // complete your file operations
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This will ensure resource closure as well as do the file operations efficiently.