# Deleting a folder structure from java

Tags: java, command, rmdir

I am finding an issue while deleting a folder from Java. I used following commands without luck. However, I am able to delete folder through command prompt using Windows 8.1:

```
String command1="rd /s /q"+Path;
String command2="rmdir /s /q \""+Path+ "\"";
String command3="del /q \""+Path+ "/*\"";
```

The exception I get in all the three cases is:

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "rmdir": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
>       at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
>       at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
>       at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:450)
>       at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:388)

Using Code:

```
try {
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

P.S.: Its a locked file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete a folder with files using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20281835/how-to-delete-a-folder-with-files-using-java)

Comment: You shouldn' use commands for that, java already provides that funtionality (in a multiplatform way).

Comment: That doesn't serves my purpose I tried many thing but it does not delete a locked file!

Comment: In you question you didn't even mention that you were trying to delete a locked file

Comment: but the exception does not care about whether the file is locked or not. It says "The system cannot find the file specified"

Comment: The real issue is that `del`, `rd` and `rmdir` are shell commands implemented within `cmd.exe` and do not have executable counterparts in Windows.  They will also fail if the file is locked, although it's not exactly clear what you mean by "locked".

Answer (score 0):

You can use: "cmd /c rmdir  /Q /S".

The system tries to run rmdir.exe and then you get this failure.

Comment: It's not portable. Better to stick to java functionality for deleting folders.

Comment: @Sarah Phillips what do mean by portable? you mean it's OS dependent? I think that it's better to do it with java too, but that is not what the question is about. He didn't ask what is the best way. He asked why this specific code is failing and I had an answer to it.