# How can ı delete the history in the allure testng but not in the terminal, we can use code

Tags: selenium, testng, allure

ı want to delete my data test history in the allure testng but not in the terminal, ı want to use some functions or any annotation in my java code

Comment: Search "delete folder in java" in stackoverflow. I found one https://stackoverflow.com/a/23678498/7574461

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void deleteDirectory(String directoryPath) throws IOException {
      Path path = Paths.get(directoryPath);
     
      try (Stream<Path> walk = Files.walk(path)) {
          walk
            .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
            .forEach(this::deleteTargetDirectory);
      }

  }

  private void deleteTargetDirectory(Path path) {
      try {
          Files.delete(path);
      } catch (IOException e) {
          System.err.printf("Unable to delete this path : %s%n%s", path, e);
      }
  }
```